# How to fill the blogger header with a very small background image

Tags: header, blogger

i am using blogger and in my blogger header i have my site title and description. I would like to add a background on it. I already picked out a background image but the size of it is very small (10px width and 10px height), how can i fil the entire background image of my blogger header?

i also want to add another column to my blogger header where i can add my logo. I also want that logo to turn into a link to my homepage.

thanks and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add background to your header with a small image you must use the css style `background-repeat: repeat;` and it will do the job for you.

With regards to your 2nd question, you should look for the for the maxwidgets in your header. change it to 2 (or more than 2) then you'll be able to add another gadget. You should also need to add the `float:left;` css attributes to the header so that it will be aligned.